# How to get the domain name only?

Tags: iphone

I have an array and I am getting the link to websites such as

```
http://clickfrom.buy.com/default.asp?adid\u003d17379&sURL\u003dhttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.buy.com%2Fprod%2Fkimberly-clark-professional-kleenex-boutique-white-facial-tissue-2-ply%2Fq%2Floc%2F66357%2F211347223.html
```

What I want is to only get the main domain for example.

clickfrom.buy.com is the main website address. How to accomplish that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you have an NSURL, you can ask for the

```
[url host]
```

This should correspond to "clickfrom.buy.com" as above.

Comment: Please see the comment below,I am getting Null.I am getting the values in array for the links

Answer (score 3):

You can it with:

```
NSString *myUrl = @"http://clickfrom.buy.com/default.asp?adid\\u003d17379&sURL\\u003dhttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.buy.com%2Fprod%2Fkimberly-clark-professional-kleenex-boutique-white-facial-tissue-2-ply%2Fq%2Floc%2F66357%2F211347223.html";

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:myUrl];

NSLog(@"%@", [url host]);
```

**EDIT**

The sequence

```
\u003d
```

in an NSString is interpreted as a universal character, so it has to be quoted for our example:

```
\\u003d
```

And will lead to an error: *\u003d is not a valid universal character*. Still there is a parsing problem, as a backslash seems to be an invalid character in the URI syntax. It has to be percent escaped.

Have a look at [RFC 2396](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt) / 2.4.3. Excluded US-ASCII Characters

> ```
> ...
> Other characters are excluded because gateways and other transport
> agents are known to sometimes modify such characters, or they are
> used as delimiters.
>
> unwise      = "{" | "}" | "|" | "\" | "^" | "[" | "]" | "`"
>
> Data corresponding to excluded characters must be escaped in order to
> be properly represented within a URI.
> ```

So doing a

```
NSString *myUrl = [@"http://clickfrom.buy.com/default.asp?adid\\u003d17379&sURL\\u003dhttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.buy.com%2Fprod%2Fkimberly-clark-professional-kleenex-boutique-white-facial-tissue-2-ply%2Fq%2Floc%2F66357%2F211347223.html" stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

should let the parsing work.

Comment: I tried this butt this is showing Null, i used this way   NSLog(@"link is  %@",[itemArray valueForKey:@"link"]);
 NSString *linkstring= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[itemArray valueForKey:@"link"]];
 NSLog(@"string is %@", linkstring);
 for (int i=0; i<[[itemArray valueForKey:@"link"] count]; i++) {
  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:linkstring];
  
  NSLog(@"%@", [url host]);
 }
 I have array from where i am getting this

Comment: Looks like as if `\u003d` is breaking the parsing.

Comment: @Sabby I've updated my answer it's the backslash causing the problems.

Answer (score 0):

Use `rangeOfString` method of `NSString` to get the bound for your domain then extract the domain text using `substringWithRange` method of `NSString`.

```
- (NSString *)substringWithRange:(NSRange)aRange
- (NSRange)rangeOfString:(NSString *)aString
```